# How to fallback to default (English) language in swift / swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization

I am using localisation in my iOS App.
I am setting device language but if device language is not available in my localisation i want to fallback / show english language.

which is better way to do this?

Thank you for help.

```
HStack {      
          Text(NSLocalizedString("welcome", comment: ""))
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you need to set localised string in localisable.string base file where you need to set value of welcome = "welcome" which is default for safe fallback in the English language. In case of no localisable.string availability, it will showcase default set text key/value.